# failed to deploy artifacts to artifactory version 6.9.6 giving an error Unauthorized 401

Tags: artifactory

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project time-demo-api: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.mycompany:time-demo-api:pom:1.0.1-20210503.122407-1 from/to snapshots (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/oneweb-snapshot): Unauthorized (401

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue is incorrect credentials being used here causing the 401 unauthorized issue. Check the settings.xml if the correct credentials are being passed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I missed something in my credentials part. I did it. I can able to push the artifacts to artifactory. Thanks for your help